# US Tax exemption for Independent student contractor working from India

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, software, contractor

I am an undergraduate computer science student, resident and citizen of India, I'll be working as an Independent student contractor for a US based software company from my home country (India), during this program I will never go to US and all my payments are a student stipend.

I am in no way a company employee and won't enjoy any benefits of a regular employee, moreover my income is project based there is no fixed based salary.

The company asks me to fill W-8BEN form for tax withholding, but I am not sure if I should pay tax to Indian Govt or to the US state. My questions are mainly:

1. Who should I pay tax to India/US state ?
2. Am I eligible for tax exemption from US because of US India tax treaty ?
   ref:  http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/india.pdf  Article 15 (Independent Personal Services)
3. Do I need to fill any formal tax forms ? If yes which one W-8BEN or 8233(asking for tax exemption) ?
4. What reason should I specify for tax exemption , being an Independent contractor  not living in US, or being a student ?

I'll be really thankful if someone can please help me regarding this.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Who should I pay tax to India/US state ?

India.

> Am I eligible for tax exemption from US because of US India tax treaty
>   ?

No, because there's nothing to exempt.

> Do I need to fill any formal tax forms ? If yes which one W-8BEN or
>   8233(asking for tax exemption) ?

You need to fill W8-BEN showing that you're not a US person for tax purposes.

> What reason should I specify for tax exemption , being an Independent
>   contractor not living in US, or being a student ?

Moot since you're not liable for any taxes in the US based on the information you've provided.